# How to list all tor circuits that have ever been established

Tags: circuit, stem

I can get the current with [this stem code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23775470/).

```
#!/bin/python
from stem import CircStatus
from stem.control import Controller


with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()

    for circ in sorted(controller.get_circuits()):
        if circ.status != CircStatus.BUILT:
            continue
    print("Circuit %s" % (circ.id))
```

**How would you list all tor circuits that have ever been established from the moment that tor has been started?**

To make things clear, instead of listing the current circuit only (say number 7) I want to list all c

Comment: Tor doesn't keep that data.

Comment: Also, that python code is wrong, the `print` statement is happening outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Millions of users use Tor and directory authority servers get requests for sending the list of active relays , the client chooses 3 relays and makes the overlay circuit. Circuits are renewed but since a few years , the guard node remains the same. If , at a given time , a consensus is studied and there are N total relays , the total possible circuits becomes " [1 * (N-1)C1 * (N-2)C1] * total number of clients ".

Answer (score 1):

There's no log for this kind of information - and for a good reason: it can hurt the privacy and anonymity of Tor. You can - technically - poll Tor regulary through Stem and keep the log for yourself, but anyway - it's a bad idea IMHO.

Can you please put some more details about what do you need it for? Maybe this task can be solved in another way?

Comment: It's not possible to create such a log, if I understand tor correctly.  A particular circuit cannot be known by a node not in the circuit.  But _IF_ each client were reporting its circuits to some logging host, it would be a heck of a long list.  Approximately X*Y*Z where X=number of entry nodes, Y=relay nodes; Z=exit nodes.

Comment: Correct. My understanding of this question is that it's a task to log all the circuits *made by this very particular local tor node*. Of course, the task of knowing other circuits is unimplementable - that fact would render Tor totally useless if it will be possible